# what is the significance of the rpc port and it's relation to the functionality of bitcoin

Tags: json-rpc

In [this outdated but seemingly comprehensive guide to creating an altcoin fork of bitcoin](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=372545.0) they make special mention of the need to change the rpc port.

Although in the intervening time the file names have changed the variables remain so I think this advice is still valid.

What is the purpose of these ports? What information do they transmit? Why are they there and why must we change them when creating a new network?

---

## Step 4- Ports(required)

```
a) bitcoinrpc.cpp 
    -change RPC port.

    Code:
    ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint(bindAddress, GetArg("-rpcport", 55883));

    Code:
    if (!d.connect(GetArg("-rpcconnect", "127.0.0.1"), GetArg("-rpcport", "55883")))

b) init.cpp
   -change RPC port

    Code:
    -rpcport= " + _("Listen for JSON-RPC connections on  (default: 55883)") + "\n" +

    -change Testnet and Common port(P2P).

    Code:
    -port= " + _("Listen for connections on  (default: 55884 or testnet: 45884)") + "\n" +

c) protocol.h

  -Testnet and P2P port again.

    Code:
    return testnet ? 45883 : 55884;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no reason why you need to change them if you're not concerned about running Bitcoin and an altcoin on the same device/IP address.

Answer (score 2):

The RPC port is the port used for tools such as `bitcoin-cli` to connect to the node and execute administrative commands (this is why it's bound by default to `localhost` / `127.0.0.1`).

The reason it should be changed is so that it doesn't create conflicts if you wanted to run your altcoin on the same system as a bitcoin node, since only one can use a given port.